# Accessing web-cam using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to automate a web-app (company specific) using Cypress which contains a page to take a picture using a web-cam. On clicking the 'Take a Photo' button, it shows an error message asking to provide access to the camera.
But, a browser pop-up is not displayed asking for permissions unlike the open-source website - https://webcamtests.com/

On looking at Cypress documentation, a default set of Chrome switches are being added to the browser before the launch which also includes
'--use-fake-device-for-media-stream'
'--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'

I've removed them using the below code that is placed in the config file .

launchOptions.args = launchOptions.args.filter((arg) => {
return arg !== '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream' && arg !== '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'
})

Also, in the documentation it specifically says this reg the default switches- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Launching-Browsers

"Disables prompts requesting permission to use devices like cameras or mics"

Am looking to see what is the corresponding switch for this and is there a way to enable the prompt to provide access?

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Cypress Version: 12.5.1
Chrome Version: 109
Platform - Mac

Note:

1. I've also tried using an open source library for enabling the camera permissions but it did not work.
   https://github.com/kamranayub/cypress-browser-permissions
2. The prompt is displayed when automated using Web-Driver.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:

```
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://webcamtests.com/',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'
    },
    followRedirect: false,
    body: {}
});
```

Above test simulate a real user request to the target website and trigger camera permissions pop-up.

Please keep in mind, it might not work for all websites as the pop-up is controlled by the website and user's browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response. cy.request is more of a service call and we wouldn't see the response in the UI right?....

Comment: You would be correct. cy.request() won't invoke any browser permission functions